# AWS - How could I check if EC2 connected with RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I created EC2 instance and security group for the RDS ( its `type: PostgreSQL` and `source: launch-wizard-1 (EC2 has)` ). And also I created the RDS instance.

Then, Is there any way how could I check if EC2 connected with RDS correctly?

The EC2 instance has no any data, it is just created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to try and connect to your RDS for testing:

1. Install db client on the ec2 instance and check connectivity.This link will help you :

https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/Setting-up-PostgreSQL

2. You can also connect from your localhost to the rds endpoint using putty and ssh tunneling.

[image]

Once connected you can use your local db client like dbeaver for connecting.

Answer (score 2):

install a psql client on the ec2 and connect
for instance

```
yum install postgres
echo '\dS' |psql -h postgres-db.ca9yqwjklxox.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

and it should give a list of tables or an error message

Comment: Should I change `postgres-db.ca9yqwjklxox.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`?

Comment: on the RDS Dashboard select the database.  Then look at the "endpoint" setting and use that

Comment: @Vorsprung i also tried same and i get this error: "psql: error: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
 Is the server running on host "XXXX.rds.amazonaws.com" (192.168.x.x) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" what does this mean?

Comment: @mgb it probably means that your networking and/or security groups are wrong.  The address you are using is unreachable on the standard postgresql port